# Python Looping Requests.get().json() and getting the value

Tags: python, json, facebook-graph-api

I picked up Python not too long ago and I am try to use Facebook Python SDK to get all the comments for a particular post.

**Problem:**

Facebook Graph API only allows 25 comments per call for a post, so to get more, i have to go the next page. Some posts can go up to few thousand comments so hard coding is worst solution.

I cannot seem to loop the request.get().

My hardcoded version:

```
      for i in JDict['data']:
           #first 25 comments
            for a in range(0,25,1):
                print i['comments']['data'][a]['message']
                print "-"*20

            #next 25 link
            myReq = requests.get(i['comments']['paging']['next']).json()
            for b in range(0,25,1):
                print myReq['data'][b]['message']
                print "-"*20

            #next 25 comments
            myReq2 = requests.get(myReq['paging']['next']).json();
            for c in range(0,25,1):
                print myReq2['data'][c]['message']
                print "-"*20

            #next 25 comments
            myReq3 = requests.get(myReq2['paging']['next']).json();
            for d in range(0,25,1):
                print myReq3['data'][d]['message']
                print "-"*20
```

The result of this code is what i need but i just can't get a loop working.

**What i tried:**

i have seen and tried the while loop in https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/examples/get_posts.py but it did not work, it just loops back to the same page's comment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.. seem like i have to answer my own question.

I download the facebook-sdk using pip but it seems it is not updated at all

refer to the updated version [here](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/commit/a6ca253148db5ca1224d594e399c9ecd8571def0), the next() method allows you to go to the next page without using the request.get()

Then, basically just create a method that loop the next() method.